# module 'ants' has no attribute 'from_numpy'

Tags: python, numpy, pip, ants, antspyx

I am working in a jupyter notebook, and used pip to install ANTsPy:

```
pip install antspyx
```

However, using the function `from_numpy` throws an error:

```
import ants

Im2Use=Im[0,:,:,:]
fixed, moving, mytx=reg(Im2Use, t_rz)
fwdtransforms=mytx['fwdtransforms']
fixed_ants= ants.from_numpy(Im2Use.astype(float))
moving_ants= ants.from_numpy(t_rz.astype(float))
mywarpedimage=ants.apply_transforms( fixed=fixed_ants, moving=moving_ants,transformlist=fwdtransforms)

AttributeError: module 'ants' has no attribute 'from_numpy'
```

How can I solve this? I've also tried importing ants using `import ants.from_numpy`, but that did not work.

Comment: Is it possible you named one of your own files `ants.py`?

Comment: No, thanks for the guidance though! It turned out to be a scipy versioning issue. I downgraded it from 1.7.3 to 1.2.0 and the issue was resolved.

Comment: If so, then please **post it as a self-answer**, so that it can be useful for others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in this case was scipy versioning. I downgraded from version 1.7.3 to version 1.2.0, which then solved the problem. Why? It's because ants library expects a function called "factorial" in scipy.misc, but version 1.7.3 moved the location of factorial.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please specify your IDE+ if you took care of activating the virtualenv?

Anyways here are the steps to make sure that the python module is propoerly installed in your virtual environment :

1. `python3 -m venv env_name` : this will create a virtual env in your current path
2. `source env/bin/activate` : this will activate your virtual env (if on windows just cd into activate within your env name `.\env\Scripts\activate`
3. If your using vscode hit ctrl+shift+p then select interpreter then go to your created env
4. now we have our virtual environment just hit `pip install antspyx` then check with `pip list` and see in your terminal if the package is propoerly installed
5. If you still have the error restart your IDE

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
from ants import from_numpy
```

Comment: Yes, it returns the error: ImportError: cannot import name 'from_numpy' from 'ants' (unknown location)

Comment: in that case refer to the comment above from @Tim Roberts